# Adding Jquery UI autosearch on newly append input in jquery-1.10.2.js version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on one application and using jquery UI autosearch feature along with **jquery-1.10.2.js** version.

I have referred online code where autosearch working fine. But example is using .live() (version jquery-1.6.2.js) which is deprecated after version 1.7 from jquery.
http://jsfiddle.net/6t74T/4/

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post">
<input id="addButton" name="addButton" type="button" value="Add an input" />
```

I have modified .live() to .on() but the code is not working as expected. You can find updated code at below
http://jsfiddle.net/ZjejY/

Need to know what am I doing wrong? As it work with .live() but not .on(). 
As far my understanding .on() provide same support as .live().

It would be good if anyone help me out to make the code workable.

Thanks in advance

Best Regards,
Jeet

Comment: in your second jsFiddle, you are not including jQuery UI. BTW, remove space at the beginning of your html string input., e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjejY/1/

Comment: Hi A. Wolff, Thanks for reply. It does not give option to select jquery UI when i select jquery1.10.1.js. In my application, I am using jquery-1.10.2.js. Do i need to use lower version of jquery to make it workable? Can you please take a look and let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ya that's just a jsFiddle behaviour. You can include jQuery UI using `External Resources` panel on the left. But i hope you aren't developping your application using jsFiddle...  http://jsfiddle.net/ZjejY/2/  EDIT: looks like i misunderstand your previous comment in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the autocomplete functionality when you create the input:

```
var addInput = function () {
    var $input = $("<input name='search' value='' class='searchInput' maxlength='20'/>")
        .appendTo("form#myForm")
        .autocomplete(options)
        .focus();
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ZjejY/3/)

Alternate method:

- Trap click event on input elements
- See if the input has the class `ui-autocomplete-input`

  - If not, trigger `.autocomplte({})` constructor

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ZjejY/5/)